# Outlook Emails missing after set up on two different computers

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have Outlook 2010 at work, and I set up an email account at home using Outlook Express to be able to check my work email at home.

After the set up was done all my emails at work disappeared. How do I recover these?

Answer (score 1):

Question:  Is your work email still in *Outlook Express* at home?

It's likely you set up your home OE instance as a POP3 client, and OE's default is to download all emails into it's local .PST file.

If so, you can create a new .PST file in OE (at home), then move your work emails into it.  Disconnect this .PST file, put a copy on a thumbdrive (or whatever), then connect that .PST file to Outlook at work.  You *may* be able to copy the emails back into your work Inbox (there are circumstances where this is not allowed and/or not successful).  Even if you cannot move the emails back, you'll still have access to them.

---

Here's the Outlook Express setting you missed:

(1) from OE's **Tools** menu, select **Accounts**

(2) select the **Mail** tab, then click on the email account in question

(3) click the **Properties** button on the right

(4) now click **Advanced**

(5) in the **Delivery** section at the bottom of this dialog box, click to leave a check mark on "Leave a copy of messages on server".  I usually leave

> `Remove from server after __ days`

**not** selected, and

> `Remove from server when deleted from 'Deleted Items'`

**selected**.